# auto postback in web custom control that have 3 binded dropdown toghether

Tags: asp.net

i have 18 custom  web user controls.
i load web user controls in div.
it work correctly and no problem on change or postback.

but i have 3 drop down list in one of custom web user controls that bind together.

for example  countries , cities , streets.

in custom web user control load i fill countries.
and in selected index changed of countries i fill cities .
and in selected index changed of cities i fill streets.

and all of 3 drop down list are auto post back.

**but** 
in countries selected index changed worked correctly and set cities(custom web user control reload correctly).

but in cities selected index changed (custom web user control relaod again and set countries again and set cities again and reset all selections).

in this state cities drop down list forget selected item.

i use update panel in page,
load controls in div that locate in page and update panel,
have 3 drop down list that bind together.
but can not set correctly.
thanks

Comment: Maybe show the update panel in the page that contains the dropdowns. Paste the code here

Comment: @m_t update your question by adding code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can control this problem and solve it by use 2 item
..... without jquery

1-a lot java script
2-.net asp c#

in onchange(client event) of city drop down list, i get selected index and set one textbox that placed in master or main page by this code

```
*temp = document.getElementById("x17_ddclans");//x17 is id of my control
    document.getElementById("th").value= temp.selectedIndex;
//th is textbox that placed in main page*
```

then in form load in main page , hide th by javascript

and in textchange of textbox i set one session that contain th.text
NOTE: auto post back enabled in textbox

because i use update panel , user can not see page postback.

and Finaly

in load page of control (x17):
i get session and set countries normaly
set city by session that contain selected value
and set street

it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is common behavior. When you are doing a post-back then at that time, of course, your drop-downs will be refreshed. So, you have to do couple of things.

1. Maintain `hidden` fields. When you make a selection for either
   `country` or a `city` drop-down, copy your `selected index` (or value) in hidden field.
2. Then on `Page_Load` event, in `Is PostBack`, fill the `country` drop-    down, and by using hidden field value, you can set the
   drop-down to previously selected value. Same process you can repeat for city drop down. 
   or 
   perform the step 2 in `SelectIndexChanged` event of drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ajax function in jQuery:

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" Width="250px" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" Width="250px" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" Width="250px" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
     ...
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            var ddl1SelectedValue = $("#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %> option:selected").val();
            var data2 = { "Value2": ddl1SelectedValue };
            var json2 = JSON.stringify(data2);
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: json2,
                url: "Default.aspx/BindDropDownList2",
                success: function (result2) {
                    ...
                    });                    },
                error: function (status, ex) {
                    alert("Error Code2: Status: " + status + " Ex: " + ex);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Do the same for the third DropDownList cascaded.